# How can I trigger scenarios automatically in Taipy?

Tags: automation, scenarios, taipy

I need to set a trigger action on Taipy and I was wondering if there was a way to automate the triggers on the scenarios in Taipy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open-source version of Taipy does not offer automatic creation and execution of scenarios; you can still create your pipelines and schedule them to run at specific times using a CRON or by coding them yourself. However, in Taipy Entreprise you have a powerful tool, the Scheduler, to create/ manage and execute scenarios automatically.